# How do I add a graphic to a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to code a Hangman game using mainly swing. It is coming along and works, but there is no Hangman graphic. I am just trying to get something to show up right now, but I don't know where to start. Here is what I have.

```
package ProjectHang;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman extends JFrame{'

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner file = null;
    try {
        file = new Scanner(new File("data/words.dat"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int size=file.nextInt();
    file.nextLine();
    int chosen=(int)(size*Math.random());
    for(int i=0; i<chosen; i++)
        file.nextLine();
    line=file.nextLine();
    new Hangman();
}
public static boolean cont=true;
public static JTextField userInput=new JTextField(20);
public static JButton confirm=new JButton("Ok");
public static JLabel header=new JLabel("HANGMAN");
public static JTextArea correct=new JTextArea("Correct Guesses",10,10);
public static JTextArea incorrect=new JTextArea("Incorrect Guesses", 10,10);
public static JTextArea unguessed=new JTextArea("", 10,10);
public static JLabel blanks=new JLabel();
public static JPanel pan=new JPanel();
public static String line;
public static int wrong=0;
ArrayList<String> chars=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> guessy=new ArrayList<String>();
 public static Graphics window;

public static MyGraphics mg;

public Hangman()
{
    this.setSize(800,800);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Hangman");
    pan.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    fillChars();
    addItem(pan, blanks, 0,1,3,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(pan, header,0,0,3,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(pan, userInput, 0,2,2,1,GridBagConstraints.EAST);
    addItem(pan, confirm, 2,2,1,1,GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    addItem(pan, correct, 0,3,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(pan, incorrect, 1,3,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(pan,unguessed,2,3,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(pan, mg, 3,0,1,4, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    confirm.addActionListener(e -> confirmClick());
    correct.setEditable(false);
    incorrect.setEditable(false);
    unguessed.setEditable(false);
    blanks.setText(word.printBlanks(line.length()));
    correct.append("\n");
    incorrect.append("\n");
    //unguessed.append("\n");
    blanks.setFont(new Font(blanks.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, 64));
    header.setFont(new Font("Cooper Black", Font.BOLD, 64));
    unguessed.append(setUnguessed());
    this.add(pan);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public void confirmClick()
{
    String guessChar;
    String guessWord;
    boolean charIsCorrect;
    boolean stringIsCorrect;
    if(userInput.getText().length()==1){
        if(!guessy.contains(userInput.getText()))
            guessy.add(userInput.getText().toLowerCase());
        else{
            userInput.setText("");
            return;
        }
        guessChar=userInput.getText();
        guessChar=guessChar.toLowerCase();
        charIsCorrect=checkChar(guessChar);
        chars.remove(userInput.getText());
        unguessed.setText(setUnguessed());
        //blanks.setText(word.setBlanks(guessChar));    
        blanks.setText(word.setBlanks(guessy));
        if(charIsCorrect)
            correct.append(guessChar+ " ");
        else 
        {
            wrong++;
            incorrect.append(guessChar+ " ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        guessWord=userInput.getText();
        guessWord=guessWord.toLowerCase();
        stringIsCorrect=checkString(guessWord);
        if(stringIsCorrect){
            blanks.setText(line);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You have won the game! Congratulations!", 
                    "WINNER",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            wrong++;
        }
    }
    userInput.setText("");
    if(wrong>=6){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "You guessed wrong too many times... \nI'm sorry, you lose.\n The correct answer was " + line,
                "LOSER",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        dispose();
    }

}
public void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, 
        int height,int align)
{
    GridBagConstraints gc=new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx=x;
    gc.gridy=y;
    gc.gridwidth=width;
    gc.gridheight=height;
    gc.weightx=100.0;
    gc.weighty=100.0;
    gc.insets=new Insets(4,4,4,4);
    gc.anchor=align;
    gc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(c,gc);
}
public boolean checkChar(CharSequence z)
{
    return line.contains(z);
}
public boolean checkString(String s)
{
    return line.equals(s);
}
public String setUnguessed()
{
    String toRet="Unguessed Characters\n";
    int counter=1;
    for(String x: chars)
    {
        if(counter%6==0)
            toRet+="\n";
        toRet+=x + " ";
        counter++;
    }
    return toRet;

}
public void fillChars()
{
    char toAdd ='a';
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        chars.add(Character.toString(toAdd));
        toAdd++;
    }
}
}
 package ProjectHang;
  import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGraphics extends JComponent {

public MyGraphics()
{
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(400,400);
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(600, 10, 10, 10);
}
}
```

I want to get this rectangle to show up on the screen, but a nullPointerException is thrown. I am fairly new to coding so there are probably a lot of mistakes. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please indicate which line your stack trace says is throwing the Null pointer.

Comment: addItem(pan, mg, 3,0,1,4, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

Comment: p.add(c,gc); is the line also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, in regards to the NullPointerExceptions. You indicate that they are on `addItem(pan, mg, 3, 0, 1, 4, GridBagConstraints.CENTER)` and `p.add(c,gc)`.

Both of these lines will throw a NullPointerException because you never instantiate the `mg` variable prior to calling `addItem`. The `addItem` method contains the `p.add(c, gc)` method call, so it will also throw the same exception. By this I mean that you never call `mg = new MyGraphics()` (or other appropriate constructor.)

---

Now, per your title question: **How do I add a graphic to a GridBagLayout?**

The simple answer is: the same way you add any other component to a GridBayLayout.

Oracle has an excellent [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), but I'll cover the hilights here.

Once you find an image for your Hangman picture, you'd add it to your application by creating a `JLabel`. Assuming your image is called `hangman.jpg`, the following boilerplate shows how to create an image `JLabel`:

```
URL imageUrl = Hangman.class.getResource("path/to/hangman.jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( imageUrl, "A hangman image" );
JLabel hangmanImage = new JLabel(image);
```

Then you'd add it to your GridBayLayout in the same way as you'd add any other components. For example, to replace the `mg` element call:

```
addItem(pan, hangmanImage, 3, 0, 1, 4, GridBayConstraints.CENTER);
```

Also I'd highly recommend giving your variables descriptive names. "Window" or "Panel" is much preferred to "pan." Once you have a working program, you may want to consider posting over at the [Code Review StackExchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for some constructive criticism of your code.